# hotkey commands -- can't get them to work

Tags: hotkeys, autohotkey

I'm just learning to use AHK, and I'm very frustrated by the fact that no hotkey commands starting with #, ^ or ! leads to any action at all. First I tried the script by Andreas Borutta for simple inputting of a selected string in the script -- no reaction. Then I tried a number of other hotkey combinations; still no reaction.

I have checked the FAQ and the documentation but cannot see that I should do anything in particular to get these commands to work. (The "ordinary" ::x::y script format works fine.)

Regards,
Mats Linder

Comment: What system are you trying to use? C#? java? web site? old cobal application?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested them all, and they work. Maybe if you post your code we could identify the problem.